# Spark Dataset joinWith API giving wrong results

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

This is a small test case to reproduce an issue that I am seeing in a join in my code

```
case class B(val b1:String, val b2: Int)
val B1 = new B("One",1)
val B2 = new B("Two",2)
val dsB = spark.createDataset(Seq(B1, B2))
dsB.show()
+---+---+
| b1| b2|
+---+---+
|One|  1|
|Two|  2|
+---+---+
val m = Map(1->"Van")
val mapget = spark.udf.register("mapget",  (b: Int) => m.get(b))
val dsB1 = dsB.withColumn("b2", mapget(dsB("b2"))).where("b2 is not null")
dsB1.show()
+---+---+
| b1| b2|
+---+---+
|One|Van|
+---+---+
val j = dsB1.joinWith(dsB, dsB1("b1") === dsB("b1"), "inner")
j.show()
+----------+--------+
|        _1|      _2|
+----------+--------+
|[One, Van]|[One, 1]|
|[One, Van]|[Two, 2]|
+----------+--------+
```

The `joinWith` result is not right. It is essentially doing a cross product. Any clue what the problem is? I have verified that `join` API works fine.

```
val j = dsB1.join(dsB, dsB1("b1") === dsB("b1"), "inner")
j.show()
+---+---+---+---+
| b1| b2| b1| b2|
+---+---+---+---+
|One|Van|One|  1|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: I also get the error that @Grisha_WeinTraub has mentioned . If you change your inner join to cross than then it works and give the output that you have shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you use a pretty old Spark version.
On Spark 2.4.4, I get the following exception when running your example:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Detected implicit cartesian product for INNER join between logical plans
LocalRelation [_1#55]
and
LocalRelation [_2#56]
Join condition is missing or trivial.
```

The reason is that the join condition in fact compares `dsB("b1")` to itself and that is always true.

A trivial solution would be to rename the column. Something like that:

```
val dsB1 = dsB.withColumn("b2", mapget(dsB("b2"))).where("b2 is not null").withColumnRenamed("b1", "b1_2")
val j = dsB1.joinWith(dsB, dsB1("b1_2") === dsB("b1"), "inner")
j.show
+----------+--------+
|        _1|      _2|
+----------+--------+
|[One, Van]|[One, 1]|
+----------+--------+
```

Comment: In fact I have a newer version

`spark version 3.0.2.19`
`Using Scala version 2.12.10 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_242)`

Comment: Also any comments on why the `join` works and not `joinWith`

Comment: Looks like in Spark 3.0 the exception is not thrown anymore and you just get the cartesian join result (SPARK-28621).
The difference between `join` and `joinWith` is just because of the way it is implemented right now. There are many related issues (e.g. SPARK-6459, SPARK-25150, SPARK-20073), some done, some in progress, hopefully this one will be fixed also one day.